# TypeORM selected subquery result not showing after querying

Tags: typeorm

So I have the following query:

```
const [discussions, total] = await em
    .createQueryBuilder(Discussion, 'd')
    .select(['d', 'u.id', 'u.firstName', 'u.lastName', 'u.image'])
    .addSelect(
      qb =>
        qb
          .select('COUNT(*)', 'commentCount')
          .from(Comment, 'c')
          .where('c.discussion_id = d.id'),
      'commentCount',
    )
    .leftJoin('d.user', 'u', 'd.user_id = u.id')
    .where('d.project_id = :projectId', { projectId })
    .orderBy({ 'd.updated_date': 'DESC' })
    .limit(limit)
    .offset(offset)
    .getManyAndCount();
```

And I'm adding a subquery select as you can see.

The query executed successfully, but the `discussions` array doesn't have property `commentCount` returned.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

Use getRaw or getRawMany instead of getManyAndCount. When you are selecting fields, typeorm can't map it to the Entities which you have defined, because there might be aliases in the select. So you have to get that data as raw data.